# RequireJS and jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I'm starting with RequireJS and I'm experiencing an issue with jquery plugin loading. Basically, when the plugin loads, it doesn't have jQuery in it's context, though I made a shim explaining it in my config.
From what I have already seen, it seems to be the right way to load plugins that don't have AMD definition, I don't understand why it doesn't work in this case.

Here is my code :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "angular-mocks": "lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks",
        "angular-route": "lib/angular-route/angular-route",
        "angular": "lib/angular/angular",
        "angular-scenario": "lib/angular-scenario/angular-scenario",
        "jquery": "lib/jquery/jquery",
        "bootstrap": "lib/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap",
        "requirejs-text": "lib/requirejs-text/text",
        "less" : "lib/less/dist/less-1.4.2"
    },
    baseUrl: '/static/js',
    shim: {
        'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular'],
        'angularMocks': {
            deps:['angular'],
            'exports':'angular.mock'
        },
        "bootstrap": ['jquery']
    },
    priority: [
        "angular"
    ],
    urlArgs: 'v=0.1'
});


require(['jquery', 'bootstrap'], function($){
    console.log($);
});
```

When I do the console.log, I have access to jQuery, but I have an error about the bootstrap loading : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Unless you're loading an old version of jQuery, you don't need a shim for it. (Look in the jQuery code, you'll see that jquery calls ``define`` if it detects an AMD-compatible environment, which RequireJS is.) I don't think this is the source of your problem though.

Comment: I have seen people using it, saying it could resolve some issues, but it's indeed not the source of my problem. I still have the issue when I delete it. I will remove it from my post, so it doesn't troubles other people.

Comment: Your shims for ``angular-route`` and ``angular-mocks`` are wrong. You must refer to them in the same way you set them in ``paths`` otherwise RequireJS is not going to shim them. This does not explain why there would be a problem with bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using Django Debug Toolbar in parallel with require, and it appears that it's loading it's own version of jQuery, messing up the order of script loading.

I removed the toolbar for now, and it's working!

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble getting a simple requirejs, jquery, and bootstrap setup to work. Took me a long time to figure out that Django Debug Toolbar loading its own jQuery was what was causing all my problems.

Comment: Second that.  Debug toolbar is constantly breaking my javascript using requirejs.  Annoying that they still can't this straight years later.